# Connection failure on HACMP service address

Tags: cluster, ansible, ibm

I have Ansible 2.6.20 installed on a Oracle Linux 6.10 with Python 2.6.6 and I'm trying to configure IBM machines running AIX 7.2 with Python 2.7.15 in a HACMP cluster.

Running ansible in console mode or ansible-playbook against a dedicated node works fine but if i try to run against the cluster service ip address I get a target unreachable error.

```
                          +--------> node A   10.1.1.11             => connection o.k.
                         /       
Ansible host 10.1.2.10  -----------> cluster service ip 10.1.1.10   => connection failure
                        \        
                         +--------> node B   10.1.1.12              => connection o.k.
```

Here is the Ansible error message (formated) with replaced user and server names for security sake.

```
 16:02:11 [/home/_ansible_/ansible]
 terminal [_ansible_@_server_]$ ansible -vvvv -i ./inventory/test.txt _target_ --user _user_ -a 'date'
ansible 2.6.17
  config file = /home/_ansible_/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/_ansible_/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 08:36:59) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]
Using /home/_ansible_/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Parsed /home/_ansible_/ansible/inventory/test.txt inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.pyc
META: ran handlers

<_target_> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: _user_

<_target_> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=_user_ -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/_ansible_/.ansible/cp/f5a095d7af _target_ '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~_user_ && sleep 0'"'"''
<_target_> (255, '', 'OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
        debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
        debug3: cipher ok: aes256-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: cipher ok: aes192-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: cipher ok: aes128-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: ciphers ok: [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug1: Applying options for *
        debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-ripemd160
        debug3: mac ok: hmac-ripemd160 [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
        debug3: mac ok: hmac-sha1 [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug3: macs ok: [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
        debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
        debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
        debug3: mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
        debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
        debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
        debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 311
        debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
        debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 12
        debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
        debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly
        ')
_target_ | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
        debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
        debug3: cipher ok: aes256-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: cipher ok: aes192-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: cipher ok: aes128-ctr [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug3: ciphers ok: [aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr]
        debug1: Applying options for *
        debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-ripemd160
        debug3: mac ok: hmac-ripemd160 [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
        debug3: mac ok: hmac-sha1 [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug3: macs ok: [hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1]
        debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
        debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
        debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
        debug3: mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
        debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
        debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
        debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 311
        debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
        debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 12
        debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
        debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Manuell SSH connection with public key authentication works fine with all three ip addresses.

My questions are:

- Is any body familiar with this issue and does know a solution for it.
- What can I do to get more debuging output?

Thans in advance
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

look at the ssd configuration on AIX, maybe the daemon is not configured to listen to all system ip addr, but only the node ip.

Comment: I can connect to all three ip addresses manually with SSH. So I think the daemon is configured right. I've updated my question with these fact.